# how can add an especific ID like tooltip to a date in Jquery Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hello i am a beginner in Jquery and i am start to use Jquery datepicker, i use this code because is good for my project but I need add an specific ID to a date because when the date was clicked will be show a Div with info

The code for show the information is not important

JQUERY

```
var disabledDays = ["2014-3-5", "2014-3-13", "2014-3-28"];
var tips = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];

//the IDs
var ids = ['first', 'second', '3er'];

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var m = date.getMonth(),
            d = date.getDate(),
            y = date.getFullYear();
        for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d, disabledDays) != -1) {
                //return [false];
                return [true, 'id='+ids[i], 'highlight', tips[disabledDays.indexOf(y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d)]];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    }

});

$("#first").click(function () {
    $("#aaa-info").show();
});
```

This is the HTMLCode

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div id="aaa-info" class="novisible"></div>
<div id="bbb-info" class="novisible"></div>
<div id="ccc-info" class="novisible"></div>
```

This is CSS

```
td.highlight {
    border: none !important;
    padding: 1px 0 1px 1px !important;
    background: none !important;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.novisible{
    display:none;
    background:#000;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
td.highlight a {
    background: #99dd73 url(bg.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;
    border: 1px #88a276 solid !important;
}
```

Comment: I change my code but i can't fix the problem i add the ids in the return line

Comment: You can check the code here http://jsfiddle.net/eligreen7/n3PBZ/5/

Comment: So when you click on a day in the calendar, you want a hidden div to show with information regarding that day of the month?

Comment: Yes, what I need is to assign the ID to the date

Comment: The information is generate for a loop but the principal problem is add an ID to a Date

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to ad an ID to each day inside the datepicker.  But I got the basic function to work.  The documentation say the `beforeShowDay` function must return an array with three elements. You were returning 4 elements.  Also you don't have to run the loop because the datapicker runs it for each day shown in the calendar.  I removed the loop and edited the return array and it works.

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oumichaelm/XZ3fv/1)

And here is the code I changed.

```
 beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(),
        d = date.getDate(),
        y = date.getFullYear();

        if ($.inArray(y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d, disabledDays) != -1) {

            return [true, 'highlight', 'Tooltip: function returned true'];
        }
        else {
            return [ false, 'highlight', 'Tooltip: function returned false']
        }
  }
```

If the goal is to display information about that day, I would add a function that would get the date, look up the hidden element on the page and return text. Something like this.

```
myTip = function(date){
    //use the date to find hidden information on page
    var myDate = date.toString();
    var tip = "This date is " + myDate;
    return tip;
};
```

Then you could change the return array to this

```
 return [true, 'highlight', myTip(date) ];
```

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oumichaelm/XZ3fv/2/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I know the function works for tooltip and class but that's the question, how to add an ID to the date? I thought it could be that way with datebeforeshow, if I can not add the ID in this way, that way I do?

Comment: I see the function below the datepicker is attaching a click to the #first element to show the hidden div. I understand you want to add an ID to the day that matches the click event, but its not the way to go in my opinion. Try also using 'onSelect' method. It will fire when a date is clicked on, then you can write a function that figures out which div to show. You could have the hidden div pop up in a dialog which the user can close when ready.  Traversing the table created by jQuery and finding the cell with the correct day doesnt fell like the right way to go.  From what i can tell

Comment: plase, can you check this? http://jsfiddle.net/eligreen7/n3PBZ/6/ i add the onSelect Method but This is my first time using datepicker and I think I have not done well

Comment: I cant check it till later tonight, but I will look at about 8:00 central time.